# How to avoid tranfer the array as a parameter

Tags: functions

I have following array:

```
data = {x^2, 2*x^2, x^3};
```

And I must send it to the following function:

```
funct[x_,data_,y_]:=Module[{i,j,m,n,r},
n=Length[x];
m=Length[data[[x[[1]]]]];
r=Table[
Subscript[data[[x[[i]]]][[j]]],{i,n},{j,m}];
LinearSolve[Transpose[r].r,Transpose[r].y]
];
```

And running the function:

```
funct[x, data, y]
```

But I would like to avoid sending unnecessary parameter to the function. 
How can I declare and use an array directly in my function?

Comment: Your code as posted does not evaluate because `Subscript[x, [[1]]]` is not valid input.  Could you try to correct that or describe how you entered it?

Comment: ok, the code should be correct. "Copy" added additional tags, I don't know why. Thanks.

Comment: `funct[x_, y_] := Module[{data = {x^2, 2 x^2, x^3}, i, j, m, n, r},...]`